# Prometheus histogram bucket reset and affect on percentile calculation

Tags: java, monitoring, prometheus, grafana

Creating a metric to count size of message coming on a Kafka topics.
Using histogram bucket to file nth percentile. Labeling using topic level only.

Want to know what happens when one of the bucket hit the max count.

is histogram counter will get resetted to zero? if yes, then this will affect the percentile calculation?

How prometheus tackle this problem?